# Omnet++ 5.3 IDE An error has occured on mac

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, omnet++

Omnet++ 5.3 is installed in mac, but the IDE does not open and shows:

> An error has ocurred. See the log files
>
> Here is the content of Log files. !SESSION Fri Apr 20 09:33:13 PKT
>   2018 ------------------------------------------ !ENTRY
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-04-20 09:33:13.502 !MESSAGE
>   Exception launching the Eclipse Platform: !STACK
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/eclipse/core/runtime/adaptor/EclipseStarter : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 51.0  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:650)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 'Unsupported major.minor version 51.0' means you have some code that requires at least Java 7 but you are using an older version of Java.

Comment: now how to update java?